# Accented filename on uri returns 404 with node.js request module

Tags: node.js, encoding, httprequest

I am using the request node module to fetch the content of some images. 
For a specific one that has an accent on its filename, request is returning a 404. 
However, it is a valid uri and it has nothing to do with encoding.
http://www.tecnofanatico.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Sin-t%C3%ADtulo-1-150x150.png

My encoding is `null` based on the documentation, as I expect binary data.
I played around with different encodings but I have no luck

What am I doing wrong here?
Am I missing a configuration option?

Comment: Is it possible the datasource doesn't have it encoded or the accent? It might be doing an exact match on the name and might not be able to find it

Comment: It is the accent. I tried to reproduce it by serving images that contained ascii characters in the filename. It happened every single time, while requesting them. I am trying to figure this out. I hope someone who have experienced it to come and save my day before I spent too much time on it :)